# How to build project and solve BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, .net, dll, visual-studio-2013, setup-deployment

I am trying to build a solution for `x86` and `x64` configurations in VS2013 but I have this issue of `BadImageFormatException` with one of the dlls. This is a Winforms application that is 99.999% managed but depends on one dll that is written in C. I am using DllImport to simply access different functions within the dll. This dll is the culprit since it comes back with `BadImageFormatException` when I build the project with x64. It works fine when I build everything with x86.

I am using a VS Setup Project targeting either x86 or x64 depending on the build configuration. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a DLL dependency which is `x86`, you will not be able to target `x64` in your solution.